# Android - Master/Detail layout with expanded master

Tags: android, layout, master-detail

I'm trying to create a master/detail layout where the master takes up all available space if the detail is not shown.
All the examples I've found, including the master/detail template from Android Studio, have the detail part always displayed, even if empty.

I want to achieve the following:

This should be the layout, when no detail is shown.

```
[[        master        ]]
```

(Expanded master view filling the whole screen)

And when the detail is displayed, this should be the layout.

```
[[ master ][   detail   ]]
```

(Master and detail side by side)

This is my current layout, but I've tried different combinations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/master"
        android:name="com.example.MyMasterFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="0dpt"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This makes "details" take up 50% of the width, even if "details" has no actual content (which is understandable, because of the weights distributing free space evenly).

The code that sets the detail content is also very simple:

```
Fragment details = new MyDetailsFragments();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.commit();
```

How do I have to change my layout so that

1. "master" takes up the whole width as long as details is not added
2. when the MyDetailsFragment is added, "master" takes up less space (e.g. 50% of the available width) and "details" takes up the rest

Can this be done purely with XML declarations, or do I have to also do things programmatically (e.g. changing layout params when "details" are added)?

Does your answer change if "master" is a ViewPager showing several RecyclerViews and "details" is content in a ScrollView (which makes using "wrap_content" a problem as their size is not really well defined)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, if I were to achieve this then I would use details fragment in the XML to have its visibility set to "Gone" and of course, my approach is programatically so I would set the visibility back to "Visible" once I inflate the Details fragment.

This before inflating

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="0dpt"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/> // Keep it gone before
```

after inflating,

```
View b = findViewById(R.id.details);
b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Let me know if its suitable now else we will search for an alternative

Comment: Thanks. setVisibility, should've thought of it.
So I just set the FrameLayout as GONE whenever no detail is shown, and when I show details, I set it to VISIBLE.

Comment: you keep it GONE initially in the XML to have it to do less work programatically

Comment: I think you meant b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
to show the details after inflating the fragment.

Comment: yes yes. I made a mistake but I have edited the answer.